# Exporting Data Using Attribute Table Widget In ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm using web app builder for ArcGis and in the configuration of Attribute table widget I did enable exporting data as CSV file but when I try to export it I get something like this in new page in the browser:

[image]

What I want is to download the file when the user hit export as CSV.

Is there any better way to export data from Attribute table ?

Comment: Help please ...

Comment: That is a CSV you are seeing downloaded to your browser.  Try IE or Chrome and see if it gives you the option to specify a download location.

Comment: @Simon you are right, it worked with Chrome .. thank you